# in what way display database table to material ui table by using node as backend and react as frontend

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
function createData(collegeName, registrarName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, action) {
  return {collegeName , registrarName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, action };
}
var rows = [
  createData("data", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Donut', 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData('Honeycomb', 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Jelly Bean', 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
  createData('KitKat', 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
  createData('Lollipop', 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
  createData('Marshmallow', 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
  createData('Nougat', 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
  createData('Oreo', 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0),
];
```

this is static data (you can check using [full code for table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#EnhancedTable.js) ) but i want to feed rows by dynamic data :[this is the response of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPUww.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use a `Map` to generate an input for your table `rows` property:

```
let list = (data && data.profiles != null) ? data.profiles.map((value, index, array) => {
        return {
            id: value.id,
            key: value.id,
            name: value.name,
        })
```

Above code is an example, change variables to your owns.